# comparing values associates with same string

Tags: perl, shell, unix, awk

I am trying to compare values in column 2 with values in column 3, across the rows. The comparison is not between values in column 2 and 3 in the same row. 
The conditions for comparison are:

(1) Value in col2 in one row is to be compared with value in col 3 in another row, when these rows have same string in column 1.

(2) Comparison only when the string in column 1 is repeated at least twice.

(3) Value in column 2 is greater than value in column 3 in a different row, when both rows have same string in column 1.

An example input file is:

```
john    0   100
john    120 200
smith   1   400
claris  300 500
claris  510 700
claris  300 500
dexter  10  400
dexter  100 300
sam 200 300
sam 310 500
tom 100 300
bruce   200 500
bruce   520 900
```

Desired output

```
john    0   100
john    120 200
claris  300 500
claris  510 700
claris  300 500
sam 200 300
sam 310 500
bruce   200 500
bruce   520 900
```

Rows with ‘dexter’  in col1 are not printed. ‘dexter’  is present in two rows but values in col 2 are smaller than values in col3 in other rows, i.e. 10 is less than  300 and 100 is less than 400. While rows with ‘bruce’ are printed because; because 2nd row with bruce has 520 in col 2 which is bigger than 500 in col3 in other row.

I tried it with awk, an example is below. Looks like I can not figure out comparing col2 with col3 in another rows, which have same string in col1

```
awk -F "\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++; b[$1]=$2; c[$1]=$3;next}   {for (i in b) if (a[$1] >2 && b[i]>c[i] ) print}' test.file test.file
```

I also tried to it in steps, first by printing only repeated lines and then comparing the associated values.
I am not able to figure out how to compare the values associated with the same string.

Comment: Why did you address your *test.file* two times, on command line? I don't understand which rule keep *dexter* out!? You wrote: *value in column 2 is greater than value in column 3*, but I don't see, in your sample, one line matching this.

Comment: I understand why you put the file twice, but @F.Hauri's other questions are quite important: _which rule keep dexter out?_   and "_You wrote: value in column 2 is greater than value in column 3, but I don't see, in your sample, one line matching this._"

Comment: To print characters in column 1 that are  repeated at least twice, using array, I passed the file twice.  I agree there are more ways. Sorry for not being clear in original question. I need to compare values in column 2 and 3, across rows,  only if they are associated with same string in column 1.

Comment: **NOT clear enough**

Comment: Yes, I meant associated with same string. Sorry my original question was not clear.

Comment: *"its not working"* That is a terrible statement of your problem. Please explain properly what is wrong.

Comment: But all of there lines have `$2<$3`? And even if you mean `$2<$3`, why is `dexter` absent in otput?

Comment: Hi Ed, sorry for not being clear in original question. I am comparing between col2 and col3 across rows associated with same string in column 1. Three rows have clarice in col1, the 2nd col in row2 has 510, which is bigger than 500 in col3 of rows 1 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you did in your attempt, we make two passes over the file. In the first, we capture for each person the number of occurrences along with their max value for column_2 and min value for column_3. For the second pass we simply test the given condition for printing.

```
NR == FNR {
    if (a[$1]) {
        # we've seen this value before in column_1
        # update the min and max values if necessary
        if ($2 > col2max[$1]) col2max[$1] = $2
        if ($3 < col3min[$1]) col3min[$1] = $3
    }
    else {
        # first time we've seen this value in column_1
        # initial the min and max to the current values
        col2max[$1] = $2
        col3min[$1] = $3
    }
    ++a[$1]
    next
}
a[$1] > 1 && col2max[$1] > col3min[$1]
```

Output:

```
$ awk -f a.awk file file
john    0   100
john    120 200
claris  300 500
claris  510 700
claris  300 500
sam 200 300
sam 310 500
bruce   200 500
```

Comment: `__/__` for decoding the OP's requirements...

Comment: I've added some comments to the code. If you need more info to understand it well let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much for a perfectly working code and for understanding my question . Could not think of assigning minimum and maximum value. To understand the code better, could you explain using 'if' and 'else'. Could we not just define the minimum and maximum for col2 and col3 while passing first time, with out if and else statements.

Comment: Good question.  You say _... just define the minimum and maximum for col2 and col3 while passing first time_ and that's the point.  We have to know whether it's the first time _for each value in column_1_. The way we know it's the first time is if `a[$1]` has it's initial value of `0`.  In that case (the else block) we just assign the values. If we have previously seen the value (the if block) we only update for higher or lower values as needed.